# What does vanilla mean in English?

Tags: meaning

The vanilla is a kind of flower, but in English, vanilla has another meaning, say 'vanilla neural network' or 'vanilla RNN'.

So, does 'vanilla' mean 'common' or 'normal'?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: I agree with Mick. You probably can understand the meaning right away if you look it up.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-vanilla-neural-network-Is-it-just-an-alias-for-a-feedforward-neural-network

Comment: Would you explain why the [dictionary definition of vanilla](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vanilla) as *plain, ordinary, or uninteresting* doesn't help?

Comment: @Mick, sorry, I am not a native speaker, and my dictionary just told me it is a kind of plant.

Comment: Online dictionaries such as the [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vanilla) and [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vanilla) will probably be more useful to you than a printed dictionary. They also provide pretty reliable BrE and AmE pronunciations.

Comment: Don't forget [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: There is no way to determine why the man who invented this used the term vanilla RNN https://books.google.com/books?id=IR9__G9tRk8C&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=vanilla+backpropagation&source=bl&ots=XEqh5dhPU3&sig=2tqr1rv7KHCpHupOuyKGkDzmDJE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6hP3uk9HRAhURxWMKHXxsB2IQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=vanilla%20backpropagation&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Vanilla" is a plant, or more specifically a *bean*, that produces a particular *flavor* or *scent*.  This is used in any number of foods and other products, from ice cream to cake to shampoo.  Because it is so common, it has come to mean "ordinary", "boring", or "unimaginative", depending on the context:

> These ideas for the new design are too *vanilla*.  We need something with more pizzazz!
>
> She got tired of her same old *vanilla* lifestyle and so gave it all up to become a professional alligator wrestler.

Comment: The phrase **plain vanilla** has been in use since the 1880s, meaning "with no other added flavorings", i.e. "simple, basic". https://books.google.com/books?id=QApBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA360&dq=%22plain+vanilla%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx4LqO6dHRAhXH64MKHX8KCCMQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22plain%20vanilla%22&f=false